# How to work with UITextFields inside of UITableViewCells?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uitextfield

I have 10 `UITableViewCells` in my `UITableView`.  Each cell has a `UITextField`.  They load fine, but I need a way to set each cell's text to its associated string.

Is there a delegate of `UITextField` that I can use to do this, and how can I determine which textfield belongs to what `NSString`, etc?

Edit:

Here is a picture of my `tableView`.  I want it to load text into each cell's `textfield` from the server then the user can edit it.  Or if there is no data on the server, the `textfield` will be blank and the user can add data and it will sync back.

I have created an `NSString` for each cell, such as `temperatureString`, `pulseString`, etc.

[image]

Comment: your question is not very clear so the responses you are getting are a bit generic. What is it that you need to do with the text fields and why do you need to set the cell's text as opposed to let the user edit it? When do you need to set the text and will you need to grab the user entry at some point? All of these questions will have an impact on how to best solve the problem.

Comment: I updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: In respect to the new info this is my new solution

So by the looks of it you are inserting `UITextField` into each cell, instead of setting the tag of each cell set the tag for each `UITextField`

First Define your tags

```
#define DESCRIPTIVE_TAG_VALUE_1 10
#define DESCRIPTIVE_TAG_VALUE_2 11
#define DESCRIPTIVE_TAG_VALUE_3 12
...
```

Use these in your `UITextField` Delegate to determine which `UITextField` belongs to which `NSString` that is if you are syncing with each update, if your not. Then obtain a reference to the `UITableView` and retrieve each of the text values of each subview of a cell that has a tag equal to one of your defines (again in a switch statement).

Once again in when working with iOS use tags they are your friends

### OR

Also you said that you are holding a reference to each `NSString`, you could just hold a reference to each `UITextField` instead that way when you sync you just have to retieve from each of your `UITextField` references.

But the Apple's best practises say to exercise the use of unique tags when dealing with mutliple views. It's really up to you

Comment: also i forgot to mention, link the associated string to the tag in your project, i didn't give code for this because i dont know how ur project is structured

Comment: same thing would apply assign each cell a unique tag and in the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" use a switch statement (like in didSelectRowAtIndexPath) to fill the Next field. ill edit my post to give an idea of what i mean

Comment: Can I just declare a `UITextField` property for each cell, and set it in the switch where I set the rest of that cell's properties?

Answer (score 0):

You must store a reference to each text field when they are created, so in the:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
```

Method, you would add this line:

```
[myTextFieldArray addObject: cell.textField];
```

Assuming textField is the property for your custom tabel view cell.

You would also set the text within the text field just after the if (cell == nil) method.

The delegate methods simply allow you to know when text is being typed, etc.

EDIT:

Considering what you've added, I agree with Sid and CStreel. Create the tags for each value:

```
#define kTemperatureTag 0
#define kPulseTag 1
// etc.
```

As an alternative to CStreel, I would assign/retrieve info matching the indexPath row, and not worry about assigning tags, because they will be the same thing if you start your tags at zero.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  // setup / retrieve cell

  NSInteger index = [indexPath row];
  switch(index)
  {
  case kTemperatureTag:
    cell.textField.text = [self.childAppointmentDictionary objectForKey:@"temperature"];
            break;
  // case ...
  }
  // ..
}
```

And:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  NSInteger index = [indexPath row];
    switch(index){
        case kTemperatureTag:
          [self.childAppointmentDictionary addObject:cell.textField.text forKey:@"temperature"];
```

Comment: I already have `cell.textField.text = [self.childAppointmentDictionary objectForKey:@"temperature"];` which should set the text of my `UITextField`.  I'm using a switch to set the text for each cell, so in each case, I should just do `[myTextFieldArray addObject: cell.textField];`, then I can retreive each textfield using its indexPath?

Comment: @Faisal It would be helpful to add this info to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

UITextfield is a subclass of UIView which has a 'tag' property. You can assign the cell's indexPath.row to be it's text field's tag as identification.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment in response to @Javy (which contains extra information you should consider adding to your original question), you could do something like the following:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
NSString *key = nil;

switch (indexPath.row)
{
    case 0:
        cell = self.temperatureCell;
        key = @"temperature";
        break;
    case 1:
        // Do other cases similarly ...
}

NSString *text = [self.childAppointmentDictionary objectForKey:key];
cell.textField.text = text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting the text in `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

It sounds like you have a specific order that you want your items to appear in which would be a good time to use an NSArray, rather than an NSDictionary.

You could, in init, or initwithNibName, create a retained array property:

```
self.myListArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"fever", @"cough", @"runny nose", nil];
```

Then, assuming that you only have 1 section, you would do `cell.textField.text = [self.myListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Is there a reason that you're using an NSDictionary for this rather than an NSArray?

Comment: Who said that I'm using a `NSDictionary`?

Comment: You did. In your comment to @Jarvy. cell.textField.text = [self.childAppointmentDictionary objectForKey:@"temperature"]; Though you're being rude, so I don't know why you expect me to help you with anything.